# is any way for reverse proxy for ssh command

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, reverse-proxy

Is any way for reverse proxy for ssh command ? ex. git clone git://~

I plan to make some server which check validation of git command.
My plan is like this.

```
Clinet git command via ssh (ex.git clone git://~~) -> server 1 (validation check) -> server 2 (git server)
```

To connect clinet to server2, I can use ssh proxy something like this

```
ssh -R 123:server1:456 server2
```

However server should have some check logic. At this point, I don't know how can I get it.

Is anyone could help?

Comment: Why do you need *reverse* proxy? Are you trying to access your local repo from the server? IMO you are doing it wong. Why not just push from local to server?

Answer (score 0):

@phd
Because users don't have access authority for server2. I also know the best way is just access server2 directly however it's impossible beacuse of my company environments. That's why I want to make reverse proxy server. And there is another reason for checking validation condition on server1 but it is also belong to my company env.